Athena partitioned table not showing data
I have created table with below script
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `conversion`(
  `id` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `unit` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `value` string COMMENT 'from deserializer')
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `partition_0` string COMMENT '')
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'quoteChar'='\"') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://prod/data/conversion/'

S3 files I have

s3://prod/data/conversion/file1.csv
s3://prod/data/conversion/file2.csv

After executing script I am running command
MSCK REPAIR TABLE `conversion`;

Now when I am trying to see the data by
select * from conversion

It has no result.
I noticed one thing.. when I see the DDL for existing portioned table in location it has '/' at the end. but when I see the location of my table it removes the '/' from end it is showing

LOCATION   's3://prod/data/conversion'

What I am doing wrong..
Thanks
